# Print array in 4 columns sorted vertically

Tags: php, sorting

I need to print an array with menu items in 4 columns, sorted vertically, and filled out like this:

[image]

Here's the markup structure to follow (5 items).

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

I've beeing trying something like this, but that doesnt work because it doesnt fill out the rows first, as the above example demonstrates:

```
$cols = 4;
$cnt = count($items);

echo "<ul>";
foreach($items as $i => $item) {
     echo "<li>" . $item->ID . "</li>";
    if(($i + 1)%$cols == 0 && ($i + 1) != $cnt) {
        echo "</ul>\n<ul>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick for what you want to do. Simply input a data array and the number of columns desired, and it will separate that array into the specified number of columns

```
<?php
    $items = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17);
    $numCols = 4;
    $result = ListArrayVals($items,$numCols);
    echo $result;
    function ListArrayVals($items,$numCols) {
        $minPerRow = floor(count($items)/$numCols);
        $remaining = count($items) % $numCols;
        $colCount = array();
        for ($i = 0;$i<$numCols;$i++) {
            if ($i < $remaining) {
                array_push($colCount,$minPerRow+1);
            } else {
                array_push($colCount,$minPerRow);
            }
        }
        $listString = '';
        $count = 0;
        for ($i = 0;$i<count($colCount);$i++) {
            $listString = $listString . "<ul>";
            for ($j = 0;$j<$colCount[$i];$j++) {
                $listString = $listString . '<li>' . $items[$count] . '</li>';
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
            $listString = $listString . '</ul>';
        }
        return $listString;
    }
?>
```

Just simply change the echo statements to wrap whatever HTML tags or whatever you want around it.

**EDIT** I fixed it. It now will work for any number of columns and input data. I have also made it into a function so it can be re-used many times.

Comment: Have you tested it with `$numCols = 4;` as the OP specified in its question?

Comment: Does not work with four columns. And why do you have missing indexes in the $items array?

Comment: It works fine for me with 4. I just tested it, and I do not know what you mean by missing indexes.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying about missing indexes, I just entered numbers into an array. It does not matter what numbers you are using, I mean you could define `$items = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...)` if you really want to. It does not particularly matter. Your question is solely asking to take an array and print it out with a specified number of columns

Answer (score 2):

try [css3 multi column property](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```
<style>
.menu {
  -moz-column-count:4; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count:4; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count:4;
}
</style>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually it isnt supported by any IE version